# Permutations of a list in scheme, works for numbers but not character as elements in list

Tags: list, scheme, permutation

I'm trying to do a program in scheme for a school assignment. Given a list, it's supposed to return all given permutations of that list. My issue is that I don't know why it would work for numbers but not characters. Doesn't seem like it would change any of the logic!

Here is my code:

```
(define (remove1 x lst)  
  (cond    
    ((null? lst)     '())    
    ((= x (car lst)) (remove1 x (cdr lst)))    
    (else            (cons (car lst)
                           (remove1 x (cdr lst))))))

(define (permute lst)  
  (cond    
    ((= (length lst) 1) (list lst))    
    (else               (apply append (map (lambda (i)
                                             (map (lambda (j) (cons i j))
                                                  (permute (remove1 i lst))))
                                           lst)))))

(permute '(1 2 3))
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to permute characters.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is used for comparing numbers; for more general comparisons, use `eq?`, `equal?` or (as has been suggested) `eqv?`.

Comment: Or, more likely, `eqv?`.